# HtmlFieldPrefix not mapping to model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Hello I have recently began work on a largely JQuery/JQueryUI based ASP .Net website. The idea was to have only one page and to have the rest of the content be dynamic, etc loaded in through dialogs and ajax.

The problem is however when a Create & a Edit form for the same model are open in dialogs at the same time some JQueryUI widgets such as the DatePicker stop working as the forms cause the DOM to have duplicate id's on the fields which are present in both.

So I tried using this code on the controller:

```
ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "Create"; // or Edit etc
```

This worked to fix the DatePicker problem, but the fields no longer mapped to the model when they were posted back to the controller.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could try specifying the same prefix when binding back:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Prefix = "Create")] CreateViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having the same issue, you could also just rename your model to "create" as shown below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateViewModel create)
{
    ...
}
```

Which I think looks nicer, but it's a bit risky. If another developer, or you, decides to change the parameter name later the form will break which is not ideal.

I figured this out as one of my forms was binding correctly and the other wasn't. One had the prefix as the parameter name and one was just "model".